# How to Disable Gutenberg & Return to the Classic WordPress Editor Without any Plugins

Tags: block-editor

for disabling gutenberg editor I use the below code
`add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false');`
but it just disable gutenberg and Classic editor never come back.
I am just curious is there any way to do that without plugins?

Comment: Why can't you just use the Classic Editor plugin? It's the officially supported way to continue using the old editor. Any other method, such as the accepted answer, runs the risk of falling out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the following to functions.php file of your current theme.

```
<?php 

/**
 * Disable Gutenberg for supported posts.
 */
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type', '__return_false', 100 );

/**
 * Disable Gutenberg action and filter hooks.
 */
function df_disable_gutenberg_hooks() {
    remove_action( 'admin_menu', 'gutenberg_menu' );
    remove_action( 'admin_init', 'gutenberg_redirect_demo' );

    remove_filter( 'wp_refresh_nonces', 'gutenberg_add_rest_nonce_to_heartbeat_response_headers' );
    remove_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'gutenberg_revisions_link_to_editor' );
    remove_filter( 'wp_prepare_revision_for_js', 'gutenberg_revisions_restore' );

    remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'gutenberg_register_rest_routes' );
    remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'gutenberg_add_taxonomy_visibility_field' );
    remove_filter( 'rest_request_after_callbacks', 'gutenberg_filter_oembed_result' );
    remove_filter( 'registered_post_type', 'gutenberg_register_post_prepare_functions' );

    remove_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'gutenberg_meta_box_save', 1000 );
    remove_action( 'submitpost_box', 'gutenberg_intercept_meta_box_render' );
    remove_action( 'submitpage_box', 'gutenberg_intercept_meta_box_render' );
    remove_action( 'edit_page_form', 'gutenberg_intercept_meta_box_render' );
    remove_action( 'edit_form_advanced', 'gutenberg_intercept_meta_box_render' );
    remove_filter( 'redirect_post_location', 'gutenberg_meta_box_save_redirect' );
    remove_filter( 'filter_gutenberg_meta_boxes', 'gutenberg_filter_meta_boxes' );

    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'gutenberg_build_files_notice' );
    remove_filter( 'body_class', 'gutenberg_add_responsive_body_class' );
    remove_filter( 'admin_url', 'gutenberg_modify_add_new_button_url' ); // old
    remove_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'gutenberg_check_if_classic_needs_warning_about_blocks' );
    remove_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'gutenberg_filter_post_type_labels' );

    remove_action( 'admin_init', 'gutenberg_add_edit_link_filters' );
    remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts-edit.php', 'gutenberg_replace_default_add_new_button' );
    remove_filter( 'redirect_post_location', 'gutenberg_redirect_to_classic_editor_when_saving_posts' );
    remove_filter( 'display_post_states', 'gutenberg_add_gutenberg_post_state' );
    remove_action( 'edit_form_top', 'gutenberg_remember_classic_editor_when_saving_posts' );
}

add_filter( 'after_setup_theme', 'df_disable_gutenberg_hooks' );

/**
 * Disable Gutenberg frontend scripts.
 */
function df_disable_gutenberg_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' );
}

add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'df_disable_gutenberg_wp_enqueue_scripts', 100 );
?>
```

Source [dfactory](https://dfactory.eu/how-to-disable-gutenberg-editor-without-a-plugin/)